# fstab errors when mounting a SSD connected via USB

Tags: mount, ntfs, fdisk

Have a 500GB SSD attached by USB, in NTFS format made by Windows Server 2012. I want to copy the contents of a folder (and subfolders) on sda2 called myfiles  to the folder `/opt/myapplic/myfiles` on the primary drive.  currently `/dev/sdb`

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

shows it as `/dev/sda1`

So I did

> sudo mkdir /media/external
>   sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -ro /dev/sda2 /media/external

and get the error

`can't find /media/external in /etc/fstab`

Comment: If the device is `/dev/sda1` why do you mount `/dev/sda2`? Apart from this, please edit the question and be more specific with the error you receive (just copy-paste the command you run and the whole answer you receive) and use code formatting!

Answer (score 1):

The written mount command have some mistakes

You want to mount readonly ?

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -r /dev/sda2 /media/external
```

You want to mount read/write

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sda2 /media/external
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation: `mount` interprets `-ro` in the same way as `-r -o` (whose meaning you can look up in the manual). This is a common behaviour of command-line tools: “short” options that expect no arguments may be directly followed by other “short” options.